# Oracle 11g FORALL and BULK DELETE Bug?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Could you please help me with the following problem:

I am using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production and I need to delete a table. 
Due to performance reasons I am trying to delete it using forall, but this doesn't work properly. Lets say I have the following table:

```
create table test
 (id number (4) not null,
  parent_id number(4),
  constraint id_pk primary key (id),
  constraint fk_id
  foreign key (parent_id)
  references test(id)
 );
```

with the following records:

```
ID         PARENT_ID  
---------- ---------- 
     1           
     2          3 
     3           
     4          5 
     5           
     6          7 
     7           
     8
```

For delete I am using the following procedure:

```
declare
   l_idx       number;
   l_err_cnt   number;

   type tp_tab_num is table of number
      index by binary_integer;

   a_pid       tp_tab_num;

   cursor c_pid
   is
      select     id
            from test
           where id <> 4
      start with parent_id is null
      connect by prior id = parent_id
      order by level desc, id;
begin
   open c_pid;

   fetch c_pid
   bulk collect into a_pid;

   begin
      forall i in a_pid.first .. a_pid.last save exceptions

         delete from test
               where id = a_pid (i);
   exception
      when others then
         l_err_cnt := sql%bulk_exceptions.count;
   end;

   close c_pid;

   for i in 1 .. l_err_cnt loop
      l_idx := sql%bulk_exceptions (i).error_index;
      dbms_output.put_line (   'Index:' || sql%bulk_exceptions (i).error_index
                            || ' Code: ' || sql%bulk_exceptions (i).error_code
                            || ' Message: ' || sqlerrm (-sql%bulk_exceptions (i).error_code)
                            || ' Pid: ' || a_pid (l_idx)
                           );
   end loop;
end;
```

The problem with forall is that if a child record is not deleted from the table (for example due to foreign key constraints to other tables - in our case record with ID 4 that I have excluded from the delete cursor)
the forall doesn't delete any other records after the parent of child that was not deleted, although I am using save exceptions.

The output of the delete procedure is:

```
Index:5 Code: 2292 Message: ORA-02292: integrity constraint (.) violated - child record found Pid: 5 -- Correct: due to constraint fk_id 

Index:6 Code: 2292 Message: ORA-02292: integrity constraint (.) violated - child record found Pid: 7 -- Incorrect: child with ID = 6 is already deleted 

Index:7 Code: 2292 Message: ORA-02292: integrity constraint (.) violated - child record found Pid: 8 -- Incorrect: ID 8 has no children
```

Please note that if I am using a for loop instead of forall, it works just fine. Only ID 4 and 5 remains not deleted.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, My real situation is that table test from the example has foreign keys to other tables too. If those are not deleted I must not delete the records from test. So if I use a single delete it will crash. With save exception I delete only what I am allowed to.

Comment: The problematic foreign key constraint is a relationship to the table itself. So whether you get a constraint violation or not depends on the order in which rows are processed. I wouldn't know whether FORALL sticks to any given order.

Comment: Hi, I couldn't find either references that the forall sticks to a given order. But I tested on the table. So if you not exclude the record ID 4 and leave the order by level desc, the delete work fine. But if you change the order by level asc the script fails with ora 02292. So it seems the forall keep count of order by. So my problem is not from the order by. I still think is an oracle bug.

Answer (score 0):

It should work when you set the constraint as `DEFERRED`. Then it applies only after the `COMMIT`.

Or use a single DELETE Statement:

```
delete from test
where id =any 
   (select id
    from test
    where id <> 4
    start with parent_id is null
    connect by prior id = parent_id);
```

**Edit:**

Do it the other way around:

```
DELETE FROM TEST
WHERE ID <>ALL 
   (SELECT ID
    FROM TEST
    START WITH ID = 4
    CONNECT BY ID = PRIOR parent_id);
```

Some notes:

- I changed the `CONNECT BY` clause, i.e. it starts from bottom instead
  from the top
- `<>ALL ()` is equal to `NOT IN ()`
- You can also use
  `START WITH ID IN (4,6)`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I set the fk_id constraint to initially deferred deferrable and the script run without error. But on commit I get
ORA-02091: transaction rolled back
ORA-02292: integrity constraint (FK_ID) violated - child record found
I think this is due to the fact that I left in the table record with ID = 4 and the script deleted it’s parent the ID=5 and on commit fails.
In fact I want to delete all other records except ID=4, because it is in relation with other tables that is why I skipped it and it parent the ID=5.

Comment: I tried the single select but it didn’t work it crashed with:
17:45:19  ORA-02292: integrity constraint (FK_ID) violated - child record found

Comment: Hi, Now the delete works, but unfortunately there is no way to know the ID of the start with clause. In my real situation ID = 4 is not deleteld becouse it has children in other tables. So if the children IDs from table test have children in other tables I must not delete them along with theire parents from table test. So I don't know which IDs to use in start with clause.